# Add program to autorun without admin rights. RegSetValueEx() returns 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: registry, access-denied, autorun, app-startup, admin-rights

I want to add my program to autorun. I know there is a registry key for it that doesnt require admin rigths to edit it.

It's

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.
```

I'm using unicode bild. I wrote a function that is for adding program to autorn.

```
void AddToRegAutorun(const std::wstring& _valueName, const std::wstring& _path)    
{        
HKEY hkey;    
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, /*KEY_SET_VALUE*//*MAXIMUM_ALLOWED*/KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)    
RegSetValueEx(hkey, _valueName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)_path.c_str(), ((DWORD)wcslen(_path.c_str()) + 1)* sizeof(wchar_t));    
RegCloseKey(hkey);    
}
```

`RegOpenKeyEx()` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS.` But `RegSetValueEx()` returns `5`

`(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Run the .exe as administrator.